# Multiple curve in image component React NAtive

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I achieve those curves at the right bottom of the image? I've tried everything. The code snippet would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Here is the image link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PlBSDbOCbba2aJbOHD6Ho5OJ057x4ljt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the image? It's not attached in the question.

Comment: Added. Please check now. @merovingienne

Comment: Image is too small, can you highlight or cut bigger size ?

Comment: check now. @JasurKurbanov

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most painless way would be have an image for that.
[image]

So, place this one over your image and you can have the multiple curves.

Link here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFGAA.png

Comment: Can you give more details about how it does not work?